# API Google map v3 : change markers' size on zoom_changed

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need some help on the Google Maps API v3.

I have a map with markers (which are pictures), informations from a database. The pictures and the map are ok at this time.

**I would like to resize the markers when changing the zoom**, but my code doesn't work (pictures disappear, replaced by the default icon). Could you help me to see what's wrong ?

Here's my code :

*// This part is ok*

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage("../images/installateurs/<?php echo $row_artisans['photo0']; ?>",
            new google.maps.Size(40, 53.2),
            new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            new google.maps.Size(40, 53.2)
        ),
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $row_artisans['Lat']; ?>, <?php echo $row_artisans['Lng']; ?>)
});
```

*// Second part where's the problem (this listener is placed just after creating the map, before rendering it)*

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    var largeur = 20 + (5 *(map.getZoom() - 9));
    var ratio = largeur / 40;
    var hauteur = 26.6 * ratio;

    for(i=0; i< markers.length; i++ ) {
        var icon = markers[i].getIcon();
        markers[i].setIcon(
            icon.url,
            new google.maps.Size(largeur, hauteur),
            new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            new google.maps.Size(largeur, hauteur)
        );
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#Marker), `setIcon` either takes a string or a `MarkerImage` object. Initially you set a `MarkerImage`, but in your listener code, you do not construct a `MarkerImage`. Try something like this instead:

```
    for(i=0; i< markers.length; i++ ) {
    var icon = markers[i].getIcon();
    markers[i].setIcon(new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        icon.url,
        new google.maps.Size(largeur, hauteur),
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        new google.maps.Size(largeur, hauteur))
    );
}
```