# change size of marker or Marker image

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**how can i change size of marker or Marker image on different events 
but marker is place on page load
only thing is to change size**

```
function onload(){
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(latt, lngg);
            img = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../Images/' + imgN, null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(30, 40));
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                id: poiId,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                draggable: false,
                icon: img,
                html: hml,
                map: map,
                draggable:true

            });
}
```

**below two lines i am using to change the zie of marker  image**

```
var iconIm = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../Images/imagesPink.png', null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(70, 90));
   marker.icon = iconIm;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

[API Google map v3 : change markers' size on zoom_changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456317/api-google-map-v3-change-markers-size-on-zoom-changed)

```
for(i=0; i< markers.length; i++ ) {
    var icon = markers[i].getIcon();
    markers[i].setIcon(new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    icon.url,
    new google.maps.Size(largeur, hauteur),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Size(largeur, hauteur))
    );
}
```