# Google Maps pinch to zoom resize marker icon

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using the V3 of Google maps to add markers on a map, and when I pinch to zoom map on a device (webview) the markers are zoomed as the map.
I tried  this answer :
[API Google map v3 : change markers' size on zoom_changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456317/api-google-map-v3-change-markers-size-on-zoom-changed)
Works for a mouse wheel zoom but not with pinch to zoom. Icons are redimensionned which is pretty bad.
Any idea?
Thank you

Comment: zoom_changed only reacts after the zooming is finished.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. Is there a workaround ofr this?

Comment: I tend to think there is no workaround.  I don't remember any code that is executed (on the map) while the map is zooming. I hope somebody corrects me